# keyboard stopped responding

Tags: keyboard

I have a situation where the keyboard stopped responding after a while. This happened before where the mouse stopped responding but the keyboard remained active.

dmesg before reboot:

```
[239536.032716] input: Microsoft Wired Keyboard 400 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3/3-1.3:1.0/0003:045E:0752.0051/input/input100
[239536.032932] hid-generic 0003:045E:0752.0051: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Microsoft Wired Keyboard 400] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.3/input0
```

after reboot the keyboard works. Plugging in and out the keyboard gives:

```
[   60.680530] input: Microsoft Wired Keyboard 400 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3/3-1.3:1.0/0003:045E:0752.0003/input/input20
[   60.680623] hid-generic 0003:045E:0752.0003: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Microsoft Wired Keyboard 400] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.3/input0
```

It's a computer that is mostly accessed remotely by SSH, but not only. What tools can be used to find the root cause?